# Click in acceptance test during continuous Ember.run.later

Tags: asynchronous, ember.js, automated-tests, acceptance-testing

In the controller I have `Ember.run.later` loop, which continuously updates the timer.

```
run: function() {
    const lastResumeTimestamp = this.get("lastResumeTimestamp");
    this.clearTimer();
    this.set('timerId', Ember.run.later(this, function() {
    // update the timer  
    // ...
      this.run();
    }, 100));
  },
```

In acceptance test I want to click button, which should pause this loop:

```
test('I want to start/pause new activity', function(assert) {
  visit('/');
  andThen(function() {
    assert.equal(find('.duration', activityBuilderSelector).text(), "0");

    click('.start-activity-button', activityBuilderSelector);
    // -->> start continuous Ember.run.later.loop, see: application cortroller

    waitFor(assert, function() {
      const val = find('.duration', activityBuilderSelector).text()
      assert.notEqual(val, "0", `notEqual 0 (${val})`);
      assert.equal(find('.title', activityBuilderSelector).text(), "New activity", "there should be activity title");
      // -->> here test waiting because of run.later loop
      click('.pause-activity-button', activityBuilderSelector);
    });
  });

  andThen(function() {
      //click('.resume-activity-button', activityBuilderSelector);
  });
});
```

but test pause before the click and waiting for loop stop.

**How can I trigger this click during loop and stop it to continue test?**

Here is little twiddle which demonstrate this issue:
https://ember-twiddle.com/a72ca75527ec4cdc0c3d1c9ebcb421e0?openFiles=tests.acceptance.my-acceptance-test.js%2C

Answer (score 1):

I just discovered, I can do this by not using test helpers:

`$('.pause-activity-button', activityBuilderSelector).click();`

but I'm not sure this is proper way to handle this.